# angularjs put an index to a model with ng-options

Tags: html, angularjs, select, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

i have a form with two selects that are populated with a JSON array that i received from the server (localhost in this moment), in the first select i have 3 days and in the second i have a lot of times that dipend of the day choosen in the first select, than i should post the choice of the two selects on the server but in this moment i post two object one for the day and one for the time so i simply want to add in ng-model an index an post it on the server for having a simple way to manage these data.

This is my code,

**SCRIPT.JS**:

```
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController)
  .factory('dataService', dataService);

DefaultController.$inject = ['dataService', '$http'];

function DefaultController(dataService, $http) {
  var vm = this;

  getEvents();

  function getEvents() {
    return dataService.getEvents()
      .then(function (data) {
        vm.data = data;
        return vm.data;
      });
  }
    vm.submit = function (){
        console.log("funzione");
        console.log(vm.form);
        var data = vm.form; // IMPORTANT
        //console.clear();
        var link = 'http://localhost/api/apiDoFix.php';
        var mail = window.localStorage.getItem("mail");
        $http.post(link, {ora: data.ora, mail: mail})
            .then(function (res){
                console.log("Dentro http.post");
                var response = res.data;
                console.log("risposta" + response);
            });
    };
}

dataService.$inject = ['$http'];

function dataService($http) {
  var service = {
    getEvents: getEvents
  };

  return service;

  function getEvents() {
    var config = {
      transformResponse: function (data, headers) {
        var result = {
          events: [],
          schedules: []
        };
        var events = JSON.parse(data);
        var dates = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
          if (dates.indexOf(events[i].day) === -1) {
            var date = events[i].day;
            dates.push(date);
            result.events.push({
              date: date
            });
          }

          result.schedules.push({
            date: events[i].day,
            time: events[i].time
          });
        }

        return result;
      }
    };

    return $http.get('http://localhos/api/apiTimes.php', config)
      .then(getEventsCompleted)
      .catch(getEventsFailed);

    function getEventsCompleted(response) {
      return response.data;
    }

    function getEventsFailed(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

**FORM.HTML**:

```
<div class="list">
                        <label class="item item-input item-select">
                            <div class="input-label">
                                Giorno:
                            </div>
                            <select ng-options="event as event.date for event in ctrl.data.events" ng-model="ctrl.form.giorno">
                                <option disabled>Seleziona un giorno </option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list">
                        <label class="item item-input item-select">
                            <div class="input-label">
                                Ora:
                            </div>
                            <select ng-options="schedule as schedule.time for schedule in ctrl.data.schedules | filter: { date: ctrl.form.giorno.date}" ng-model="ctrl.form.ora" ng-disabled="!ctrl.form.giorno">
                                <option disabled>Seleziona un orario </option>
                            </select>
```

How can i solve this problem?

Thank's

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Sravan what???

Comment: "so i simply want to add in ng-model an index", didn't understand this point.

Comment: i want that the user see the options in the selects but the choice that he does it isn't the day and the time but an index in both the selects, for example if he choice the first day and the firs time i should manage the value 1 for the day and the value 1 for the time @Sravan

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

You can use **`ng-options="index as value for (index, value) in values`**

Eg:

```
<div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input item-select">
        <div class="input-label">
            Giorno:
        </div>
        <select ng-options="idx as event.date for (idx, event) in ctrl.data.events" ng-model="ctrl.form.giorno">
            <option disabled>Seleziona un giorno </option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input item-select">
        <div class="input-label">
        Ora:
        </div>
        <select ng-options="idx as schedule.time for (idx, schedule) in ctrl.data.schedules | filter: { date: ctrl.form.giorno.date}" ng-model="ctrl.form.ora" ng-disabled="!ctrl.form.giorno">
            <option disabled>Seleziona un orario </option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

[Here is a fiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/12570/)

**Method 2:**

In `ng-options` you can use `indexOf`

```
<div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input item-select">
        <div class="input-label">
            Giorno:
        </div>
        <select ng-options="ctrl.data.events.indexOf(event) as event.date for event in ctrl.data.events" ng-model="ctrl.form.giorno">
            <option disabled>Seleziona un giorno </option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input item-select">
        <div class="input-label">
        Ora:
        </div>
        <select ng-options="ctrl.data.schedules.indexOf(schedule) as schedule.time for schedule in ctrl.data.schedules | filter: { date: ctrl.form.giorno.date}" ng-model="ctrl.form.ora" ng-disabled="!ctrl.form.giorno">
            <option disabled>Seleziona un orario </option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: thank's, works but there is an error because with this code (method 1) the selects print all the same data, ie the first select data (the first is correct) are repeated in the other two selects @Sravan

Comment: didn't get you, the first selected data in the other select? can you please be more specific

Comment: yes, sorry, with this code the first select is right but in the second select i've always the same data whatever choice was made in the first select and are always the data that are belonging at the first day